# Gson Json Parsing in Java

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, parsing, gson

I want to parse json list. I have used springboot project, database is H2. Database contains few data.

I have successfully displayed json data via @getmapping function.
Code is as below,

```
File-----> ProductController.Java 
@GetMapping("/products_from_db")
        public  List<Product> getProducts_from_db() { 
            return productservice.findAll() ;
        }
```

Second File is as Follows.

```
File ----> Product.java

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
//@ToString
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private int price;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", price=" + price +
                '}';
    }
```

output:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mango",
    "price": 98
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Strawberry",
    "price": 92
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Cadbury",
    "price": 85
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "yash",
    "price": 100
}]
```

I want to display only name and price in back end code only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Gson isn't as straight forward in certain aspects as, for example, Jackson - where you can simply use the annotation `@JsonIgnore`.

On the other hand, Gson seems to have more flexibility (although a little too technical sometimes.)

In the case of Gson you have two main options to achieve what you want:

1. Mark the field you want to ignore as `transient`: `private transient String id` (in this case you have to make sure that this won't cause any side effects in your application.)
2. You can use the very flexible capabilities of Gson, especially the annotation `@Expose`. for example:

   @Expose(Serialize = false)
   private String id;

You can find more examples and details [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/gson/gson-exclude-or-ignore-fields/) and [here](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.html).

Please, let us know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working as expected. May i know one more thing, can you share me tutorial links or videos if any for notations in spring boot..?

Comment: @YashZode No problem! However, could you list the ones you already have tried, please? I'm assuming that you already searched and tried.